# IntelliJ cannot find some generated TensorFlow references

Tags: python, tensorflow, intellij-idea

I wrote some TensorFlow code in Python. It compiles and runs fine. However, some names cannot be resolved by IntelliJ.

The error displayed when hovering over such an unfound reference is `Cannot find reference '...' in 'tensorflow._api.v1.data'`; the expanded message starts with `Inspection info: This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't.`.

One example of such an unresolved reference is `tf.data.Dataset`. When I navigate to `tf.data`, there is only an `__init__.py` module in there, that starts with `# This file is MACHINE GENERATED!`.

There are many such packages, and they are in `External Libraries`. What is the proper way to fix this issue?

Comment: What is your TF version, OS, Python version and how did you install TF ( pip or conda )?

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal TF 1.12, Python 3.6, IntelliJ Community 2018.3.2, Windows 10.0.17763; I use pip.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem with tf.contrib part. I installed the TensorFlow version 1.10.0 with Anaconda. It uses the conda package manager. To install TF

```
conda install tensorflow==1.10.0
```

Installing with Conda solved my problem.